# How can I figure out why git is deleting a file on an incoming merge?

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch that I pulled up from master. I have files that were added in master subsequent to the branch being created. When I merge that branch down, it's deleting the files in master, which I do not want.

There are a couple of different active branches, and there has been some merging back and forth between them. I suspected that perhaps the files got added in another branch, perhaps manually, were subsequently deleted, and then that branch got merged into my problem branch. However, extensive use of `git log` on that file (including options like `--all` and `--follow`) reveals nothing in the problem branch. The only change I've been able to find that involves these files are the original adds in master. I have also cranked up the verbosity of the merge, which didn't seem to give me all that much more detail.

I cannot for the life of me see why git is deleting this stuff. Anyone have a suggestion as to what sort of data-mining tools I can use in git to figure out what's going on here?